# Redirecting assembly in .Net Core 3.1 App

Tags: c#, .net-core, ibm-mq

I have an application that references IBM MQ client dll located in the bin folder.
Currently, new version of the IBM MQ client installed on the server.
How to force my application to use dll from full client installation directory instead of the dll located in the bin folder?

Comment: Have you tried through NuGet? Why do you need it from the dll? I see in their documentation that they have this for .NET standard. I have found this -> https://www.nuget.org/packages/IBMMQDotnetClient/9.1.5?_src=template

Comment: when mq client dll referenced from the full installation it offeres very detailed logging including error information.

Comment: Sth like that i guess then? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2244881/how-to-know-full-paths-to-dlls-from-csproj-file